# Uncertainties with my first SEM - Questions online-guides didn't answer me

Tags: r, statistics, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am working on my first SEM and struggle with a few things. I have no mentor or anyone to think this through with and thought that therefore this might be the right place to ask. I would like to kindly ask for your opinions and feedback regarding my approach and my conclusions. Thanks to everyone who puts in the effort to read this in advance

Here are a few key points:

- N = 416 (outliers removed)
- 8 latent variables; 6 factors (see the image)
- Hypotheses include direct and indirect effects

The general model with the underlying hypotheses:
[Model with hypotheses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i3u6.png)

Things I struggle with / questions:

1. Model interpretation
   To test the direct effects (H1 & H2) I first set up the model without the mediators. Fit indices are good and both hypotheses were confirmed. Adding the mediators one direct effect (H1) becomes non-significant. Model fit is better without a direct path as well, what I interpret as there is a full mediation. The question I am asking myself is, do I only interpret the mediation model, since it clears more variance and is therefore “superior” or would I conclude that H1 (direct effect) is still confirmed, but mediator 1 just fully mediates the relationship?

1.1 This outcome makes me a bit suspicious in general. Without the mediators there is a highly significant (p = < .001) effect which explains 20% of DV1’s variance. After inserting the mediator, it is all explained by the mediation…Could this situation mean that mediator 1 and DV1 are correlated too strongly? CFA indicated that mediator1 and DV1 might as well run as one factor.

2. Covariance within latent variables
   In my CFA-stage MI-indictors advised me to allow some variables to convey. Covariance of latent or manifest variables beyond the boundaries of a factor don’t make sense to me. But what about covariance within one latent factor on the same order-level? Does this make sense to improve model fit and are there downsides?
3. The use of control variables
   At first, I checked if any control variables like age and gender influence my model-variables. And yeah, there were significant correlations. Do I then insert the control variables for all the latent ones? Or just for the endogenous ones?
4. Possibility to test a correlation hypothesis in lavaan?
   As far as I understand the info on lavaan, covariance is “only” the residual covariance. However, H3 aims to test the correlation between DV1 and DV2. In order to test that, would you perform another correlation (cor.()-function)?

If you would like to answer, but miss some information please ask. I will happily resubmit my lines of code, outputs or whatever helps the discussion!
Thanks so much for all your answers in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: This is not the right place to ask. Stack Overflow is for clear, specific programming questions. If you want advice for a statistical analyses, perhaps try a more appropriate site like [stat.se] for statistical advice or (RStudio Community)[https://community.rstudio.com/] for a more general discussion forum.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was concerned about that already but unsure. Sorry for the mispost. Could you doublecheck you recommendation above? I was trying to get to "stat.se" but that site doesnt exist.

Comment: The link should have been https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: In addition to https://stats.stackexchange.com/, I highly recommend joining the SEMNet listserve and maybe the lavaan discourse.